# Eloquent Simple Relationship doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get a specific timer with the relationship to the timer_themes, something like:

```
Timer::with('timer_theme')->find(1);
```

but it returns:

```
>>> Timer::with('timer_theme')->find(1);
    => App\Timer {#3245
         id: 1,
         user_id: 1,
         slug: "test",
         end_time: "2020-03-25 21:59:14",
         is_locked: 1,
         created_at: "2020-03-24 18:26:33",
         updated_at: "2020-03-25 19:59:14",
         theme_id: 1,
         timer_theme: null,
       }
```

My models are setup like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Timer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'timers';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'slug',
        'end_time',
        'is_locked',
        'timer_theme_id'
    ];

    public function timer_theme() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TimerTheme');
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TimerTheme extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'timer_themes';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'css_path',
        'view_path'
    ];

    public function timerThemeOptions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\TimerOptions');
    }

    public function timer() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Timer');
    }
}
```

These are my database tables:

```
timers
-------
id
user_id
slug
end_time
is_locked
theme_id
```

and

```
timer_themes
-------------
id
name
view_path
css_path
```

I've messed around with the relationships in the models, but still haven't found a solution that will work.

Comment: Try using `TimerTheme::class` instead of the string `timer_theme` inside your `with`

Comment: >>> Timer::with(TimerTheme::class)->find(1)->toSql()
Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/RelationNotFoundException with message 'Call to undefined relationship [TimerTheme] on model [App/Timer].'

Comment: Is `timer_theme` the name of your table?

Comment: @BarryD. `with()` takes the name of the relationship, not the name of the class.

Comment: From the example on the docs (`$users = User::with('podcasts')->get();`) it seems they _are_ using a string.

Comment: @miken32 Yes, I just read the docs. I posted my knee-jerk reaction as a comment. :)

Comment: How is it set up in the DB? Is everything correct there, i.e. has the Timer row a relationship maintained to the corresponding timer_theme?

Comment: What is the foreign key called? You seem to alternate between `theme_id` and `timer_theme_id`. I suspect that might be your problem.

Comment: Sometimes Laravel is naming the referencing attributes in a way one would not expect, that's why having a look at the actual database schema after running your migrations is definitively worth it.

Comment: tthanks @miken32, that was definitely the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your relationships are set up correctly, and work as expected:

https://implode.io/944GOS

However, the database layout, code, and debug output you've provided show some conflicts in the name of the foreign key to the `timer_themes` table.

Ensure your `timers` table has a column called `timer_theme_id`, and then your models should look like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Timer;
use App\TimerOptions;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TimerTheme extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'css_path',
        'view_path'
    ];

    // renamed this method for consistency
    public function timer_options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TimerOptions::class);
    }

    public function timer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Timer::class);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use App\TimerTheme;
use App\Model\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Timer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'slug',
        'end_time',
        'is_locked',
        'timer_theme_id'
    ];

    public function timer_theme()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TimerTheme::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

You're better off specifying the class names programatically instead of as a string, in case they change. Note that specifying the table name for your model is not necessary when using standard naming conventions as you are. (It doesn't hurt, of course.)

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize I named the column theme_id instead of timer_theme_id.